# my site theme problem

Tags: my-site, theme

I have a student portal and i want to change students "my contents" theme. However i cant change all students "my content "theme at the same time.

I have to it one by one. http://****.edu.tr/students/username/ i can change like this url on SPD. When i want to open http://****.edu.tr/students/ on SPD

it goes to http://****.edu.tr/ directly.

How can i change "my contents" theme at the same time?

Thank you and good works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Designer is not the tool to perform batch updates on MySites (or any sites). You should use PowerShell for an automation like this (are you using 2007 or 2010?). In any case [this blog post claims](http://www.powershell.nu/2009/03/08/set-themeps1-set-theme-in-sharepoint-using-powershell/)* the script will automatically change theme so you should try it.

(*) Please note: I haven't tested the script.